# Is it possible to create a custom filter in tradingview cryptoscreener

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

In the tradingview cryptoscreener it is possible to set all sorts of filters.
As for EMA's, i like to filter on the 13 EMA. Is it possible to create a custom filter in the cryptoscreener?

Comment: Can you add more information and links. Are you on about https://uk.tradingview.com/crypto-screener/ (which are present to 5, 10, 20, 30 50, 100, 200). There possible is a way to make an indicator for a select amount of symbols. What are you monitoring? Price above/below crossing EMA 13.

Comment: Have a look at this script https://uk.tradingview.com/script/4TJ0F64J-Ultimate-EMA-Screener/

Comment: And i am looking to filter out:
-coins where the 13 EMA crosses with 21 EMA
-price above EMA's
-Best is 4 hour chart

As for the script, this would fit in my chart as i understand.
Is there no way to actually add a script to the screener itself?

Comment: If I was you I would drop PineCoders (User name in Trading View) an email just to double check if you can make custom EMA inputs. I only have the standard account so it might be something the higher membership accounts have access to.

Answer (score 3):

Not for the moment. The TV screener only works with the filters already included in it. [A search of the Public Library on “screener”](https://www.tradingview.com/scripts/screener/) will return a few examples of scripts that use [`security()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_security) to screen from pre-determined and limited lists of symbols.

A Pine screener is in plans, but there is no ETA for it yet.